# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for User type=value_error.missing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am a bit new to pydantic and fastapi, however I am getting normal response when requesting get all users, but started to get this error when trying to create a new User. It's an API made from fastapi and sqlalchemy libraries on python 3.11.4

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for User
response -> username
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> email
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> access
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

and user classed in my schemas.py file look as following:

```
import pydantic as _pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel as _BaseModel
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional

#USERS
class _UserBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: str
    access: str

class UserCreate(_UserBase):
    username: str
    email: str
    password: str
    access: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode=True

class User(_UserBase):
    id:int
    projects: List["Project"] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode=True
```

Models.py

```
class User(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    password = Column(String)
    access = Column(String)
    projects = _orm.relationship("Project", back_populates="owner")
    tasks = _orm.relationship("Task", back_populates="assigned_user")

    def verify_password(self, password:str):
        return _hash.bcrypt.verify(password, self.password)
```

and in services.py

```
async def create_user(db: _orm.Session, user: _schemas.UserCreate):
    db_user =  _models.User(email=user.email, password=_hash.bcrypt.hash(user.password), username=user.username, access=user.access)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
```

Could some please explain why this error is happening?

Tried to change places of fields in Schemas.py, between _ProjectBase, ProjectCreate and Project, however the error does not go away.

Answer (score 0):

in UserCreate class u are inheriting from UserBase, so u dont have to define the same attributes again.

Second thing is that in services.py you define response model as UserCreate which does not have id atribiute which you are trying to return. You should return User:

```
async def create_user(db: _orm.Session, user: _schemas.User):
```

this should work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After the changes pointed out above, I figured that the issue was in pydantic type check from my main.py function. After removing `response_model=_schemas.User` and replacing it with `status_code=200` it stopped giving me this error.